# Scroll flash before scrolling

Tags: javascript, web, reload

After page reload i need to maintain scroll position.I used this code.

```
window.onload = function () {
            document.onscroll = function () {
                sessionStorage.scrollTop = document.body.scrollTop;
            };
            if (sessionStorage.scrollTop != "undefined") {
                document.body.scrollTop = sessionStorage.scrollTop;
            }         
        };
```

But before scrolling screen flashes. It`s like very quick animate. How can i fix it?

Thanks for answer! But now i have another problem. I add this to the head of document.

```
    <style type="text/css">
        .no_fouc {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.documentElement.className = 'no_fouc';
    </script>
```

This to document ready event.

```
window.onload = function () {
            document.onscroll = function () {
                sessionStorage.scrollTop = document.body.scrollTop;
            };
            if (sessionStorage.scrollTop != "undefined") {
                document.body.scrollTop = sessionStorage.scrollTop;
            }
            $('.no_fouc').removeClass('no_fouc');
        };
```

And  it`s not scrolling at all

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because the page starts rendering before the onload event happens. You could try hiding the page content and displaying it after scrolling is done (much as you would for hiding templates from frameworks like angular before they have a chance to render) for ex http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/web-designer/how-to-prevent-flash-of-unstyled-content-on-your-websites/